# Django : filter Datefield in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using **Django 1.5.8**

I'd like to filter `Datefield` type data in template like following code.

- express with `timesince` format for recent articles
- express with `date` format for old articles

*some_template.html*

```
{% for article in articles %}

    {# recent articles #}
    {% if article.created >= (now - 7 days) %}
        {{ article.created|timesince }}

    {# old articles more than one week past #}
    {% else %}
        {{ article.created|date:"m d" }}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Is there a solution to handle `{% if article.created >= (now - 7 days) %}` by django's own template tags?

Or do I have to make new custom filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm sure it's possible to do this with a custom template tag, I think you'll find it is a lot easier to implement this test in your model code. For example:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
class Article(models.Model):
    [...]
    def is_recent(self):
        return self.created >= date.today() - timedelta(days=7)
```

Then your template can be:

```
{% for article in articles %}
  {% if article.is_recent %}
    {{ article.created|timesince }}
  {% else %}
    {{ article.created|date:"m d" }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```